# Can't find executable `mac_listener` while running mix phx.server

Tags: macos, elixir, macos-mojave

Mac listener cannot be found on Macos Mojave, though it is installed.
I tried to recompile the dependency and reinstall the modules but still the problem persists.

the mix deps.compile file_system returns this error.

```
mix deps.compile file_system

14:34:40.227 [info]  Compiling file system watcher for Mac...
==> file_system
c_src/mac/cli.c:1:10: fatal error: 'getopt.h' file not found
#include <getopt.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

14:34:40.469 [error] Could not compile file system watcher for Mac, try to run "clang -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices -Wno-deprecated-declarations c_src/mac/*.c -o priv/mac_listener" manually inside the dependnecy.
```

Comment: i couldn't find a solution, but your problem is the same as this https://github.com/falood/file_system/issues/57. One person in the thread says it's a problem relating to python paths

Comment: which dependency is using 'file_system'?

Comment: Thank you for the reply,  actually I'm running phoenix and the live reload raises that issue, do you mean what is the python/anaconda dependency using file_system?

Comment: You need to install the development library. Installing the application itself is not enough. I have no idea how to install dev libs on macs though. `brew blah blah-dev` or somewhat similar should do.

Comment: The development libraries are installed, I even reinstalled them without any success

Comment: Since `brew` basically sucks in installing the dependencies for the development libraries, maybe an explicit installation of `getopt-dev` might resolve the issue.

Comment: I upgraded the default version of getopt to the latest but couldn't `brew link` it, some issues with the default MacOS getopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the solution was this.

First

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Then

```
mix do deps.get, deps.compile
```